# What's a more modern and user-friendly alternative to ART (A Reporting Tool)?

Tags: gratis, linux, mysql, reporting, dashboard

I'm looking for a web-based software which lets me very quickly build dashboards with charts, etc. based on MySQL queries. What I need is:

- Interactive charts the user can "play with"
- User parameters (also for drilldown), with a lot of customizablity
- Conditional SQL - change parts of the query based on user parameters (more than just changing a value)
- Scheduled jobs running in background (a query might take 10 minutes)
- Report groups
- Support for multiple data sources
- Modern and intuitive user interface
- Self-hosted
- Free (or very inexpensive) for business use
- runs on my linux host

I found a tool, ART (A Reporting Tool), which sounds like it can do what I need very well. The problem is, ART version 2 is very cumbersome and unintuitive, and looks very bad compared to today's UI standards. ART version 3 alpha looks perfect, but it isn't functional yet (you can't create reports).

Do you know any other alternative?

I found lots of full BI solutions like Pentaho Community, etc. but they seem like overkill, or at least I was overwhelmed and didn't know where to start with those.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Could you state which operating system / environment you have on your host?

Comment: Linux. Everything else is flexible.
We use CentOS+nginx+PHP5.4 for most applications, though, so this would require the least changes, but it's no problem to use something else.